# Custom Facebook Like Box in PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I know that I can embed Facebook's own [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) on to a web page, but as many people have found out it can no longer be styled as much as you used to be able to do (removing the border is about the best you can do it seems).

So I was wondering whether it would be possible to build my own customised Like Box so that I have control over the styling of it, and make it fit in with the design of the web page it needs to go on?

I've been attempting to work my way through the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) on the Facebook site and know how to get some information such as the number of "likes" a page has and other information about the page itself, but I can't seem to find out how to pull a random number of profile pics for people that have liked the page (the same as how it works on the Like Box social plugin basically).

Thanks.